# Selective python string replacements

Tags: python, string, function, replace, pi

I am trying to replace the `pi` with `math.pi` using the following Python function.

```
def cleanup(x):
  return x.replace("pi", "math.pi")
```

I have the following strings:

```
a = "2*pi"
b = "the pink elephant"
```

The output for `cleanup(a)` is: `2*math.pi` -- This works well!

The output for `cleanup(b)` is `the math.pink elephant` -- problem: I don't want "text" to change.

Can someone help me?

Comment: If you are fixing up Python code, just define "from math import pi" and you don't have to substitute anything.  And now that Python permits Unicode identifiers, you can also add this import to your code: `from math import pi as π` and then you can write code like 'C = π*D'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for regular expressions, particularly, the "word boundary" (`\b`) assertion:

```
import re
print re.sub(r'\bpi\b', 'math.pi', "2*pi")
print re.sub(r'\bpi\b', 'math.pi', "the pink elephant")
```

Comment: One is always learning. This would be the "manual" way: `(?<!\w)pi(?!\w)`

Comment: A great resource for regular expressions in Python: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a more sophisticated filter, you should look into regular expressions, there is a module for it built-in into Python

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html